# Postgresql: Can't access table created for application user

Tags: postgresql, permissions, spring-data, acl, flyway

I'm working on a self education project. My current goal/blocker is to create PostgreSQL database setup with managed migrations that will have minimal required permissions for separate migration and application user. I've managed so far to get migration part working, but setup I've got is too restrictive for supposed application user. What I want to achieve is that application user can use tables while not being able to change schema.

I'm using PostgreSQL from Docker and Flyway for migrations in Spring Java Application.

Here's my init script for database on container creation:

To run this I do `docker compose up` on terminal `1`.

```sql
CREATE DATABASE hot_update;

CREATE USER flyway_migration WITH PASSWORD 'flyway_secret';
CREATE USER spring_application WITH PASSWORD 'spring_secret';

\c hot_update

DROP SCHEMA public;

CREATE SCHEMA application_schema AUTHORIZATION spring_application;
ALTER ROLE spring_application SET search_path = application_schema;

GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA application_schema TO flyway_migration;
GRANT TEMPORARY ON DATABASE hot_update TO spring_application;

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA application_schema TO spring_application;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
  IN SCHEMA application_schema
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO spring_application;
```

Then content of 1st migration applied by flyway_user. To run this I execute `mvn spring-boot:run` on terminal `2`.

```
CREATE TABLE simple_entity
(
    id UUID,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    text varchar(255)
);
```

And it doesn't work, at first I've thought that somehow I've messed up my r2dbc driver config in spring app, but it doesn't even work from `psql`. Example session bellow on terminal `3`.

```
wiktor@desktop-bep0pt7-1:~/code/postgres-hot-update> psql -U spring_application -h localhost -d hot_update
Password for user spring_application: 
psql (15.2)
Type "help" for help.

hot_update=> SELECT * FROM simple_entity;
ERROR:  permission denied for table simple_entity
```

For reference output of information commands in `psql`

```
hot_update=> \dn
             List of schemas
        Name        |       Owner        
--------------------+--------------------
 application_schema | spring_application
(1 row)

hot_update=> \d+
                                                      List of relations
       Schema       |         Name          | Type  |      Owner       | Persistence | Access method |  Size   | Description 
--------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------------+-------------+---------------+---------+-------------
 application_schema | flyway_schema_history | table | flyway_migration | permanent   | heap          | 16 kB   | 
 application_schema | simple_entity         | table | flyway_migration | permanent   | heap          | 0 bytes | 
(2 rows)

hot_update=> \dp
                                           Access privileges
       Schema       |         Name          | Type  | Access privileges | Column privileges | Policies 
--------------------+-----------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------------+----------
 application_schema | flyway_schema_history | table |                   |                   | 
 application_schema | simple_entity         | table |                   |                   | 
(2 rows)

hot_update=> \ddp
                          Default access privileges
  Owner   |       Schema       | Type  |          Access privileges          
----------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------
 postgres | application_schema | table | spring_application=arwdDxt/postgres
(1 row)
```

In case anyone wished to try it out locally here's link to branch having WIP state I had when writing this question.

https://gitlab.com/stmi-blog/postgres-hot-update/-/tree/5-add-spring-data-reactive-repository-over-dummy-table

I've cross-posted same question to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where the problem is, when you assigned the default privilege, it should have been done as flyway_migration.

```
hot_update=# \c - flyway_migration 
You are now connected to database "hot_update" as user "flyway_migration".
hot_update=> 
hot_update=> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
hot_update->   IN SCHEMA application_schema
hot_update->   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO spring_application;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
hot_update=> 
hot_update=> CREATE TABLE application_schema.simple_entity
hot_update-> (
hot_update(>     id UUID,
hot_update(>     created_at TIMESTAMP,
hot_update(>     text varchar(255)
hot_update(> );
CREATE TABLE
```

As you see now:

```
hot_update=> \c - spring_application 
You are now connected to database "hot_update" as user "spring_application".
hot_update=> select * from simple_entity ;
 id | created_at | text 
----+------------+------
(0 rows)
```

And now for owner you have **flyway_migration** not **postgres**:

```
hot_update=> \ddp
                                  Default access privileges
      Owner       |       Schema       | Type  |              Access privileges              
------------------+--------------------+-------+---------------------------------------------
 flyway_migration | application_schema | table | spring_application=arwdDxt/flyway_migration
(1 row)
```

OR you must create table as **postgres** CASE2:

```
hot_update=# \c - flyway_migration 
    You are now connected to database "hot_update" as user "flyway_migration".

hot_update=> 
hot_update=> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA application_schema REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES FROM spring_application;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
hot_update=# drop table application_schema.simple_entity ;
DROP TABLE

hot_update=> \c - postgres
You are now connected to database "hot_update" as user "postgres".
hot_update=# ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA application_schema GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO spring_application;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
hot_update=# 
hot_update=# CREATE TABLE application_schema.simple_entity
hot_update-# (
hot_update(#     id UUID,
hot_update(#     created_at TIMESTAMP,
hot_update(#     text varchar(255)
hot_update(# );
CREATE TABLE
hot_update=# \c - spring_application 
You are now connected to database "hot_update" as user "spring_application".
hot_update=> select * from simple_entity ;
 id | created_at | text 
----+------------+------
(0 rows)
```

And you have:

```
hot_update=> \ddp 
                          Default access privileges
  Owner   |       Schema       | Type  |          Access privileges          
----------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------------------
 postgres | application_schema | table | spring_application=arwdDxt/postgres
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

While the answer provided by @ITLoook is correct and points to right direction, the solution I've went with is to use `FOR ROLE` clause in `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
  FOR ROLE flyway_migration
  IN SCHEMA application_schema
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO spring_application;
```

This is explained in documentation for [ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html)

This section

```
Parameters

target_role

The name of an existing role of which the current role is a member. 
If FOR ROLE is omitted, the current role is assumed.
```